# How do I structure poorly structured content based off of following/preceding-sibling text() node predicates?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Based on the source XML below, I want to capture the text nodes and `<emphasis>` elements that do not contain `<emphasis bold="yes">`NOTE#:`</emphasis>`, with their corresponding `<emphasis bold="yes">`NOTE#:`</emphasis>` element.

Source XML:

```
<section>
  <para>
    <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE1:</emphasis> This is the text of the first note 1 <emphasis bold="yes">that should only be in the <emphasis italic="yes">first</emphasis> subsection occurance of note one.</emphasis>. This is the second sentence of the first note one. <emphasis italic="yes">Here is some other text</emphasis> that can appear. <emphasis bold="yes">Marvin Gaye is an excellent musician1.</emphasis> Play it for your girlfriend1 <emphasis italic="yes">now1.</emphasis>.
    <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE2:</emphasis> This is the text of  the first note two2.1 <emphasis italic="yes">The Isley Brothers are also good.2.1</emphasis>
    <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE1:</emphasis> This is the text of the second note one.1.2 <emphasis italic="yes">My girlfriend loves them1.2</emphasis>
    <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE3:</emphasis> This is the text of the first note three3.1.
    <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE1:</emphasis> This is the text of the third note one.1.3<emphasis italic="yes">She is going to make me dinner tonight1.3</emphasis>
    <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE3:</emphasis> This is the text of the second note three.3.2<emphasis italic="yes">Steak and potatos3.2</emphasis>
    <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE2:</emphasis> This is the text of the second note two.2.2<emphasis italic="yes">And then some wine2.2</emphasis>
  </para>
</section>
```

Current XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*|@*|text()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="section">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="para/emphasis[preceding-sibling::emphasis[@bold='yes' and text()='NOTE1:']]"/>
  <xsl:template match="para/emphasis[preceding-sibling::emphasis[@bold='yes' and text()='NOTE2:']]"/>
  <xsl:template match="para/emphasis[preceding-sibling::emphasis[@bold='yes' and text()='NOTE3:']]"/>
  <xsl:template match="para/text()[preceding-sibling::emphasis[@bold='yes' and text()='NOTE1:']]"/>
  <xsl:template match="para/text()[preceding-sibling::emphasis[@bold='yes' and text()='NOTE2:']]"/>
  <xsl:template match="para/text()[preceding-sibling::emphasis[@bold='yes' and text()='NOTE3:']]"/>

  <xsl:template match="para/emphasis[@bold='yes' and text()='NOTE1:' and not(position()=last())]">
    <subsection>
      <para>
        <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE1:</emphasis>
        <xsl:copy-of
          select="following-sibling::text()[not(preceding-sibling::emphasis[@bold='yes' and text()='NOTE2:'])  and not(preceding-sibling::emphasis[@bold='yes' and text()='NOTE3:'])] |following-sibling::emphasis[not(contains(string(), 'NOTE1:'))  and  not(contains(string(), 'NOTE2:'))  and not(contains(string(), 'NOTE3:'))]"
        />
      </para>
    </subsection>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="para/emphasis[position()=last() and position() > 1  and @bold='yes' and text()='NOTE1:']">
    <subsection>
      <para>
        <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE1:</emphasis>
        <xsl:copy-of
          select="following-sibling::text()[position() = 1]|following-sibling::emphasis[not(contains(string(), 'NOTE1:'))  and  not(contains(string(), 'NOTE2:'))  and not(contains(string(), 'NOTE3:'))]"
        />
      </para>
    </subsection>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="para/emphasis[@bold='yes' and text()='NOTE2:' and not(position()=last())]">
    <subsection>
      <para>
        <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE2:</emphasis>
        <xsl:copy-of
          select="following-sibling::text()[not(preceding-sibling::emphasis[@bold='yes' and text()='NOTE1:'])  and not(preceding-sibling::emphasis[@bold='yes' and text()='NOTE3:'])] |following-sibling::emphasis[not(contains(string(), 'NOTE1:'))  and  not(contains(string(), 'NOTE2:'))  and not(contains(string(), 'NOTE3:'))]"
        />
      </para>
    </subsection>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="para/emphasis[position()=last() and position() > 1 and @bold='yes' and text()='NOTE2:']">
    <note>
      <para>
        <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE2:</emphasis>
        <xsl:copy-of
          select="following-sibling::text()[position() = 1]|following-sibling::emphasis[not(contains(string(), 'NOTE1:'))  and  not(contains(string(), 'NOTE2:')) and not(contains(string(), 'NOTE3:'))  ]"
        />
      </para>
    </note>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="para/emphasis[@bold='yes' and text()='NOTE3:' and not(position()=last())]">
    <note>
      <para>
        <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE3:</emphasis>
        <xsl:copy-of
          select="following-sibling::text()[not(preceding-sibling::emphasis[@bold='yes' and text()='NOTE2:'])  and not(preceding-sibling::emphasis[@bold='yes' and text()='NOTE1:'])] | following-sibling::emphasis[not(contains(string(), 'NOTE1:'))  and  not(contains(string(), 'NOTE2:'))  and not(contains(string(), 'NOTE3:'))]"
        />
      </para>
    </note>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="para/emphasis[position()=last() and position() > 1 and @bold='yes' and text()='NOTE3:']">
    <note>
      <para>
        <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE3:</emphasis>
        <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::text()[position() = 1]|following-sibling::emphasis[not(contains(string(), 'NOTE1:'))  and  not(contains(string(), 'NOTE2:'))  and not(contains(string(), 'NOTE3:'))  ]"/>
      </para>
    </note>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current output:

```
<root>
  <para>
    <subsection>
      <para>
        <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE1:</emphasis> This is the text of the first note 1 <emphasis bold="yes">that should only be in the <emphasis italic="yes">first</emphasis> subsection occurance of note one.</emphasis>. This is the second sentence of the first note one. <emphasis italic="yes">Here is some other text</emphasis> that can appear. <emphasis bold="yes">Marvin Gaye is an excellent musician1.</emphasis> Play it for your girlfriend1 <emphasis italic="yes">now1.</emphasis>.
        <emphasis italic="yes">The Isley Brothers are also good.2.1</emphasis>
        <emphasis italic="yes">My girlfriend loves them1.2</emphasis>
        <emphasis italic="yes">She is going to make me dinner tonight1.3</emphasis>
        <emphasis italic="yes">Steak and potatos3.2</emphasis>
        <emphasis italic="yes">And then some wine2.2</emphasis>
      </para>
    </subsection>
    <subsection>
      <para>
        <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE2:</emphasis>
        <emphasis italic="yes">The Isley Brothers are also good.2.1</emphasis>
        <emphasis italic="yes">My girlfriend loves them1.2</emphasis>
        <emphasis italic="yes">She is going to make me dinner tonight1.3</emphasis>
        <emphasis italic="yes">Steak and potatos3.2</emphasis>
        <emphasis italic="yes">And then some wine2.2</emphasis>
      </para>
    </subsection>
    <subsection>
      <para>
        <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE1:</emphasis>
        <emphasis italic="yes">My girlfriend loves them1.2</emphasis>
        <emphasis italic="yes">She is going to make me dinner tonight1.3</emphasis>
        <emphasis italic="yes">Steak and potatos3.2</emphasis>
        <emphasis italic="yes">And then some wine2.2</emphasis>
      </para>
    </subsection>
    <note>
      <para>
        <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE3:</emphasis>
        <emphasis italic="yes">She is going to make me dinner tonight1.3</emphasis>
        <emphasis italic="yes">Steak and potatos3.2</emphasis>
        <emphasis italic="yes">And then some wine2.2</emphasis>
      </para>
    </note>
    <subsection>
      <para>
        <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE1:</emphasis>
        <emphasis italic="yes">She is going to make me dinner tonight1.3</emphasis>
        <emphasis italic="yes">Steak and potatos3.2</emphasis>
        <emphasis italic="yes">And then some wine2.2</emphasis>
      </para>
    </subsection>
    <note>
      <para>
        <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE3:</emphasis>
        <emphasis italic="yes">Steak and potatos3.2</emphasis>
        <emphasis italic="yes">And then some wine2.2</emphasis>
      </para>
    </note>
    <subsection>
      <para>
        <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE2:</emphasis>
        <emphasis italic="yes">And then some wine2.2</emphasis>
      </para>
    </subsection>
  </para>
</root>


Desired output:

<root>
  <para>
    <subsection>
      <para>
        <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE1:</emphasis> This is the text of the first note 1 <emphasis bold="yes">that should only be in the <emphasis italic="yes">first</emphasis> subsection occurance of note one.</emphasis>. This is the second sentence of the first note one. <emphasis italic="yes">Here is some other text</emphasis> that can appear. <emphasis bold="yes">Marvin Gaye is an excellent musician1.</emphasis> Play it for your girlfriend1 <emphasis italic="yes">now1.</emphasis>.
      </para>
    </subsection>
    <subsection>
      <para>
        <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE2:</emphasis>This is the text of  the first note two2.1<emphasis italic="yes">The Isley Brothers are also good.2.1</emphasis>
      </para>
    </subsection>
    <subsection>
      <para>
        <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE1:</emphasis> This is the text of the second note one.1.2 <emphasis italic="yes">My girlfriend loves them1.2</emphasis>
      </para>
    </subsection>
    <subsection>
      <para>
        <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE3:</emphasis> This is the text of the first note three3.1.
      </para>
    </subsection>
    <subsection>
      <para>
        <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE1:</emphasis> This is the text of the third note one.1.3<emphasis italic="yes">She is going to make me dinner tonight1.3</emphasis>
      </para>
    </subsection>
    <subsection>
      <para>
        <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE3:</emphasis> This is the text of the second note three.3.2<emphasis italic="yes">Steak and potatos3.2</emphasis>
      </para>
    </subsection>
    <subsection>
      <para>
        <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE2:</emphasis> This is the text of the second note two.2.2<emphasis italic="yes">And then some wine2.2</emphasis>
      </para>
    </subsection>
  </para>
</root>
```

Comment: YIIIIIKES. Please reformat your question so that your code looks like code. It's the little "{}" button at the top of your editor.

Comment: I have added indentation to the XML in your quetion so that it can be read. I have also removed what I presume is a spurious `xsl:template` opening tag which was followed by an identical one. This is illegal as templates cannot contain other templates. I also added a closing `xsl:stylesheet` tag which was missing.

Comment: Please, explain better what output (and any rules) is exactly required. In its current form this isn't clear. Also, please, provide the exact wanted output from the transformation. If possible, replace the current example with a smaller one and format the XML document and the wanted result in such a way, so that no horizontal scrolling is required.

Comment: In the future I will try harder.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your requirement correctly, I think you may have slightly overcomplicated your XSLT. It looks like you simply want to group the nodes, with the start of each group being represented by an **emphasis** node with text state "NOTE"

Assuming you are using XSLT 2.0 (as you current XSLT is marked version="2.0") then say hello to the useful **xsl:for-each-group** command, which should be just what you need. In your case, grouping nodes beginning with the relevant **emphasis** elements:

```
<xsl:for-each-group 
    select="node()" 
    group-starting-with="emphasis[starts-with(text(), 'NOTE')]">
```

Within in this, you would output your **subsection** and **para** elements, and then iterate over the elements in the group to copy them

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
```

You would use the [XSLT identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) to output the **emphasis** elements themselves.

Here is the happily much-shorter XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="para">
      <para>
         <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-starting-with="emphasis[starts-with(text(), 'NOTE')]">
            <subsection>
               <para>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
               </para>
            </subsection>
         </xsl:for-each-group>
      </para>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<section>
   <para>
      <subsection>
         <para>
            <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE1:</emphasis> This is the text of the first note 1 
            <emphasis bold="yes">that should only be in the 
               <emphasis italic="yes">first</emphasis>subsection occurance of note one. 
            </emphasis>. This is the second sentence of the first note one. 
            <emphasis italic="yes">Here is some other text</emphasis>that can appear. 
            <emphasis bold="yes">Marvin Gaye is an excellent musician1.</emphasis>Play it for your girlfriend1 
            <emphasis italic="yes">now1.</emphasis>. 
         </para>
      </subsection>
      <subsection>
         <para>
            <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE2:</emphasis>This is the text of the first note two2.1 
            <emphasis italic="yes">The Isley Brothers are also good.2.1</emphasis></para>
      </subsection>
      <subsection>
         <para>
            <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE1:</emphasis>This is the text of the second note one.1.2 
            <emphasis italic="yes">My girlfriend loves them1.2</emphasis></para>
      </subsection>
      <subsection>
         <para>
            <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE3:</emphasis>This is the text of the first note three3.1. </para>
      </subsection>
      <subsection>
         <para>
            <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE1:</emphasis>This is the text of the third note one.1.3 
            <emphasis italic="yes">She is going to make me dinner tonight1.3</emphasis></para>
      </subsection>
      <subsection>
         <para>
            <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE3:</emphasis> This is the text of the second note three.3.2 
            <emphasis italic="yes">Steak and potatos3.2</emphasis></para>
      </subsection>
      <subsection>
         <para>
            <emphasis bold="yes">NOTE2:</emphasis> This is the text of the second note two.2.2 
            <emphasis italic="yes">And then some wine2.2</emphasis></para>
      </subsection>
   </para>
</section>
```

See http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1314 for more examples on how to group in XSLT 2.0